# Download pdf using asp.net codefirst

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf, code-first

Hi everyone so I am trying to create an application using asp.net mvc with a code first database that allows the users to be able to upload and download images so far I have got it to save to the database and display but I am having trouble with my controller to work out how to allow the user to download the pdf file.

currently in the controller there are these issues

> where is underlined saying PoliciesImageModel does not contain the definition for where
>   . and policies is underlined saying cannot convert PoliciesImageModel to byte

Thanks for anyhelp with this issue

> Update I am using Matts answer but PoliciesImages and the file are not being recognised

View

```
 @model List<MyProject.Models.PoliciesPostVM>
 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FileName)
 @Html.ActionLink("Download", "PoliciesDownload", new { id = item.ID})
 }
```

Controller

```
   public FileContentResult PoliciesDownload(int ID)
    {
        if (ID == 0) { return null; }
        PoliciesImageModel policies = new PoliciesImageModel();

        policies = policies.Where(a => a.ID == ID).SingleOrDefault();
        return File(policies, "application/pdf");
    }
```

model

```
 public partial class PoliciesPostModel
    {
        public PoliciesPostModel()
    {
            Pdfs = new List<PoliciesImageModel>();
    }
    [Key]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Heading is Required")]
    [Display(Name = "File Name")]
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PoliciesImageModel> Pdfs { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> File { get; set; }
}

public class PoliciesImageModel
    {
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public virtual PoliciesPostModel Post { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
public class PoliciesImageVM
    {
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
public partial class PoliciesPostVM
    {
    public PoliciesPostVM()
    {
            Pdfs = new List<PoliciesImageVM>();
    }

    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Files { get; set; }
    public List<PoliciesImageVM> Pdfs { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PoliciesPostModel> Posts { get; set; }   
}
```

DbConext

```
public class EFDbContext: DbContext
{
    #region Policies
    public DbSet<PoliciesPostModel> PoliciesPosts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PoliciesImageModel> PoliciesImages { get; set; }
    #endregion Policies   
    //other Dbsets are here too....
}
```

Comment: `Where` is a LINQ extension. You need the appropriate namespace referenced in a `using` statement to use it as an extension method. Add `using System.Linq` to the top of your file. And you can only use `Where` on collection objects.

Comment: Your policies var is an instance of a ViewModel "PoliciesImageModel".. so you can't perform a linq query off that. Doesn't look right?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to return a `FileContentResult`. That is just an array of bytes (and that is exactly what a PDF file is). You will need to use the `Path` property to search on disk and get the contents of the PDF file into a byte array. Then stream that array out instead of your `PoliciesImageModel`

In addition, you are creating a new, individual `PoliciesImageModel` object, not a list of `PoliciesImageModel` from the database. You'll need to get the list from the database context and do the filter on that list.

```
public ActionResult PoliciesDownload(int ID)
{
    if (ID == 0) { return null; }
    using (var context = new DBContext()) {
        PoliciesImages policies = context.PoliciesImages;
        var policy = policies.Where(a => a.ID == ID).SingleOrDefault();
        byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(policies.Path);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=policies.DisplayName + ".pdf");
        return File(fileBytes , "application/pdf");
    }
    return null;
}
```

*This has not been tested. I'm probably missng something. But this is the general idea.*

Comment: Hi Matt first off thanks for your help, but I seem to be getting errors with the words File and where (i have using system.Linq and all the required using statements and check by hitting ctrl fullstop on them ) it says  PoliciesImageModel does not contain the definition for where and secondly it says controller.File(byte[],string) is a method which is not valid given the context

Comment: Oh I see, so there are two things going on it looks like. My previous answer just addressed the "cannot convert PoliciesImageModel to byte". I just looked again. You are trying to do a `Where` on a `PoliciesImageModel`, but it's not a `List` or `IEnumerable` or anything.

Comment: Hi Matt again thanks for your help you have fixed the where bit but there is a couple issues 
It says - EFDbContext.PoliciesImages cannot be used like a method
     - PoliciesImages could not be found
     - controller.File(byte[], string) is a method which is not valid given the context
also return null is underlined in green saying its unreachable should I put that in an else,Also sorry for the hassle matt

Comment: Every implementation of EntityFramework is different, so there is bound to be a bug or two in my sample since i can't really test it. Now that I am looking at it, I don't think you need `context.PoliciesImages();`. Instead, try `context.PoliciesImages;` (without the parentheses).

`PoliciesImages policies = context.PoliciesImages;`

Comment: Hi Matt thanks for your help and I understand that you cant test it just thought I would let you know that its down to two issues for some reason it doesn't recognize the first PoliciesImages and the file thing is still an issue I wonder is it due too PoliciesImages not being regonised gonna edit the dbcontext part of this post encase It would help anyone find out what this issue is and again thanks for your time you have been very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this code it doesnt downloaded it but instead opens the pdf up in a new tab and displays it.
Controller

```
 public ActionResult PoliciesDownload(int ID)
        {
            if (ID == 0) { return null; }
            PoliciesImageModel resume = new PoliciesImageModel();
            EFDbContext rc = new EFDbContext();
            resume = rc.PoliciesImages.Where(a => a.ID == ID).SingleOrDefault();
            return File(resume.Path, "application/pdf");
        }
```

View

```
        @Html.ActionLink("View Pdf",  "PoliciesDownload", new { id = item.ID }, new { @target = "_blank" })
```